# How to reoder the stacks in a ggplot bar chart to reflect the reordering of the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am searching for a way to reorder the stacks of my bar chart to reflect the reordered legend so that the figure is more intuitive and interpretable, with "decreased greatly" on the left end of the graph, and "increased greatly" on the right, with "stayed the same" in the middle.

I was able to easily reorder the legend, but not the associated stacked bars. Please advise.

Also, the colors are chosen to be colorblind-friendly, so I am committed to using the ones selected.

First, generate the data.

```
pop <- c("hunt", "hunt", "hunt", "hunt", "hunt", "hunt", "hunt", 
                "trap", "trap", "trap", "trap", "trap", "trap", "trap",
                "gp", "gp", "gp", "gp", "gp", "gp",  "gp", 
                "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", 
                "SL", "SL", "SL", "SL", "SL", "SL", "SL", 
                "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL")

res <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
         1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
         1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
         1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
         1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
         1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

per <- c(1.6, 1.3, 2.26, 7.32, 26.94, 31.13, 29.46, 
         0.49, 0.56, 0.61, 4.25, 17.71, 29.82, 46.57, 
         2.57, 3.86, 5.15, 12.81, 26.75, 23.73, 25.13, 
         2.09713, 2.317881, 3.97351, 11.479029, 20.198675, 23.289183, 36.644592, 
         3.571429, 7.397959, 7.653061, 15.05102, 34.438776, 22.44898, 9.438776, 
         2.658487, 3.885481, 5.316973, 13.496933, 32.719836, 25.562372, 16.359918)

mydata <- data.frame(pop, res, per)
```

Then, make sure to load the proper libraries.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
```

Next, translate response options to a text response.

```
## translate to discrete response options
mydata <- mutate(mydata, tres = recode(res, "1" = "Decreased greatly",
                                       "2" = "Decreased moderately",
                                       "3" = "Decreased somewhat",
                                       "4" = "Stayed about the same",
                                       "5" = "Increased somewhat",
                                       "6" = "Increased moderately",
                                       "7" = "Increased greatly"))
```

You can see the structure of the data here

```
head(mydata)
> head(mydata)
   pop res   per                  tres
1 hunt   1  1.60     Decreased greatly
2 hunt   2  1.30  Decreased moderately
3 hunt   3  2.26    Decreased somewhat
4 hunt   4  7.32 Stayed about the same
5 hunt   5 26.94    Increased somewhat
6 hunt   6 31.13  Increased moderately
```

Then, generate the chart. Reminder - the colors are chosen to be colorblind-friendly, so I am committed to using the ones selected.

```
leg_ord <- levels(with(mydata, reorder(tres, per)))

ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data = mydata, aes(x = reorder(pop,per), y=per, fill=tres), position="stack", stat="identity")+
  coord_flip() + 
  ggtitle("perception of population change")+
  ylab("Percentage")+
  xlab("population")+
  #  scale_fill_brewer(palette="PRGn")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+ 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=leg_ord, 
                    values=c("Decreased greatly"="#D55E00", 
                             "Decreased moderately"="#CC79A7",
                             "Decreased somewhat"="#E69F00",
                             "Stayed about the same"="#999999",
                             "Increased somewhat"="#0072B2",
                             "Increased moderately"="#56B4E9", 
                             "Increased greatly"="#009E73"))
```

The resulting chart looks as follows.  Unfortunately, "Stayed about the same" is on the left side of the graph, rather than centered. And really, all of the bars in the stacked bar chart are misordered. I would like them to be ordered in the same manner as the legend.

[image: bar chart, misordered bars]

How can I fix the order of the legend and bars? I have tried reading several other posts but invariably it messes up the graph. Please advise.

Thank you!

ETA 1 - I included the wrong image and ggplot code initially, but it is fixed now.

ETA 2 - Here is the final code I am going to end up using. I wanted to pass it along in case anyone else sees this in the future and has similar data/issues. Thank you to the people who commented to help me out - much appreciated and I wouldn't have figured it out without your help.

```
leg_ord <- levels(with(mydata, reorder(tres, res)))
mydata$tres <- factor(mydata$tres, rev(leg_ord))

ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data = mydata, aes(x = reorder(pop,per), y=per, fill=tres), position="stack", stat="identity")+
  coord_flip() + 
  ggtitle("perception of population change")+
  ylab("Percentage")+
  xlab("population")+
  #  scale_fill_brewer(palette="PRGn")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+ 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=leg_ord, 
                    values=c("Decreased greatly"="#D55E00", 
                             "Decreased moderately"="#CC79A7",
                             "Decreased somewhat"="#E69F00",
                             "Stayed about the same"="#999999",
                             "Increased somewhat"="#0072B2",
                             "Increased moderately"="#56B4E9", 
                             "Increased greatly"="#009E73"))
```

The resulting chart looks like this:
[image]

I like how it's very clear what the majority opinion is (how far to the left the neutral option is), and I think that data at either end of the scale is quite clearly presented.

Thanks again!

Comment: Set up your data so the `fill` variable is a factor with appropriate levels: `mydata$tres <- factor(mydata$tres, rev(leg_ord))`.

Comment: Thank you @Axeman! This works great.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is helpful for diverging bar plots. May be a bit different than your desired result

```
mydata <- mutate(mydata, tres = recode(res, "1" = "Decreased greatly",
                                       "2" = "Decreased moderately",
                                       "3" = "Decreased somewhat",
                                       "4" = "Stayed about the same",
                                       "5" = "Increased somewhat",
                                       "6" = "Increased moderately",
                                       "7" = "Increased greatly")) %>% 
  mutate(favorable = case_when(
    tres %in% c('Stayed about the same', 
                'Increased somewhat',  
                'Increased moderately', 
                'Increased greatly') ~ 'y', 
                TRUE ~ 'n'
  )) %>% 
  mutate(diverPercent = case_when(
    favorable == 'y' ~ per, 
    TRUE ~ -per
  ))

leg_ord <- levels(with(mydata, reorder(tres, per)))

ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data = filter(mydata, diverPercent > 0), aes(x = reorder(pop,diverPercent), y=diverPercent, fill=tres), position="stack", stat="identity") +
  geom_bar(data = filter(mydata, diverPercent < 0), aes(x = reorder(pop,diverPercent), y=diverPercent, fill=tres), position="stack", stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() + 
  ggtitle("perception of population change")+
  ylab("Percentage")+
  xlab("population")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+ 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=leg_ord, 
                    values=c("Decreased greatly"="#D55E00", 
                             "Decreased moderately"="#CC79A7",
                             "Decreased somewhat"="#E69F00",
                             "Stayed about the same"="#999999",
                             "Increased somewhat"="#0072B2",
                             "Increased moderately"="#56B4E9", 
                             "Increased greatly"="#009E73")) +
  theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal')+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you! Very interesting. Is there a way to center the "stayed about the same" responses? I can see how that form would be very useful, but more so if "stayed about the same" is centered.